# Open Parent Application (WatchOS 2.x+)

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2

I am trying to get an update from the parent app, but I don't want to bring the parent app to the foreground when the request is sent from the Apple Watch. I ultimately would like to bring the parent app to a background state, have it run it's required method and send it back to the watch.

Specifically, is there a way to open the parent app and have it reside temporarily in a background state from WatchOS 2.0+?

I have looked into this:
[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:[NSDictionary new] reply:nil];

But this is unavailable starting Watch OS 2.0 apparently.

(Parent App) App Delegate:

```
@interface InterfaceController() <WCSessionDelegate>

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *networkConnectionLabel;

@end

@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context
{
    [super awakeWithContext: context];
}

- (void) willActivate
{
    [super willActivate];
    [self startSessionToParentDevice];
}

- (void) startSessionToParentDevice
{
    if ([WCSession isSupported])
    {
        [[WCSession defaultSession] setDelegate: self];
        [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
    }
}

- (void) session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext
{
    [[self networkConnectionLabel] setText: [applicationContext objectForKey:@"CurrentConnectionStatus"]];
}
```

(Watch App) Interface Controller:

```
@interface InterfaceController() <WCSessionDelegate>

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *networkConnectionLabel;

@end

@implementation InterfaceController

- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context
{
    [super awakeWithContext: context];
}

- (void) willActivate
{
    [super willActivate];
    [self startSessionToParentDevice];
}

- (void) startSessionToParentDevice
{
    if ([WCSession isSupported])
    {
        [[WCSession defaultSession] setDelegate: self];
        [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
    }
}

- (void) session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext
{
    [[self networkConnectionLabel] setText: [applicationContext objectForKey:@"CurrentConnectionStatus"]];
}
```

Comment: "openParentApplication" method has been depreciated after watchOS2. and yes watchConnectivity is the solution now. but I don't see any foreground/background methods  of WCSession for sending information between iPhone & Watch.What issue you are actually facing?

Comment: Muneeba, I need to send the iPhones current network status to the watch so it can update a label with either wifi, cellular or No Service. But it can only do this if it's in the foreground or background, because I'm using reachability.

Comment: If you need to perform any network request on watch , you can do that directly via NSURLSession, watchOS 2 supports that too. Check this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-711/

Comment: Would I be able to determine the type of network it is using if I do that? Like does the reachability framework work on the watch? I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: NSURLSession on Apple Watch allows Watch apps to connect to known Wi-Fi networks and make HTTP requests as mentioned in this link https://www.macstories.net/stories/watchos-2-review/2/. So as far as as type of network is concerned the only option on watch is wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Use the WatchConnectivity's sendMessage APIs on the watch side to wake the iOS app up in the background