# How can I open the parent app on iPhone from my WatchKit app with watchos 2?

Tags: iphone, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to open the parent application of my Apple Watch app with watchos 2.

I'm tried use

```
+ (BOOL)openParentApplication:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
                        reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo,
                                        NSError *error))reply
```

but it is not available for WatchKit extensions running in watchOS 2.

Also, i tried the methods as 
`sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:` and `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:` then in the class `Appdelegate.m` of iphone I implemented

```
 - (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler {  where calls [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:***$protocoltoOpenApp***]];
```

- but with these methods send information to iphone app but not open
  the background app.

Please help.

Comment: you might want to take a peek [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487780/open-parent-application-watchos-2-x)

Comment: I read the link but there isn't any solution. I would like to open iphone app from watch like app. camera.